# PHP ActiveRecord in CodeIgniter and mysql datetime field

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I just added PHP ActiveRecord to my CodeIgniter installation.  I'm running a few tests now and am very confused by a few things.  I have a products table in mysql, and when I use ActiveRecord to retrieve the first row in the table, this is the output I get:

```
Product Object
(
    [errors] =>
    [attributes:ActiveRecord\Model:private] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [ext_id] => 347
            [ext_type_id] => 1
            [sku] => SYB-RIU-SUP
            [url] => http://domain.com
            [name] => SUP Wall Storage Rack
            [thumbnail_url] => https://thumburl.com
            [sort_order] => 20
            [profitability] => 40
            [last_google_update] => ActiveRecord\DateTime Object
                (
                    [model:ActiveRecord\DateTime:private] => Product Object
 *RECURSION*
                    [attribute_name:ActiveRecord\DateTime:private] => last_google_update
                    [date] => 2014-05-21 05:01:12
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => UTC
                )

            [last_internal_update] =>
            [discontinued] => 0
            [stock_notes] =>
            [deleted] => 0
            [created_on] => ActiveRecord\DateTime Object
                (
                    [model:ActiveRecord\DateTime:private] => Product Object
 *RECURSION*
                    [attribute_name:ActiveRecord\DateTime:private] => created_on
                    [date] => 2014-03-25 22:31:58
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => UTC
                )

        )

    [__dirty:ActiveRecord\Model:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [__readonly:ActiveRecord\Model:private] =>
    [__relationships:ActiveRecord\Model:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [__new_record:ActiveRecord\Model:private] =>
)
```

What do the `*RECURSION*` lines mean in the object?  Is that expected or is that a problem?  Also, let's say I need to access the last_google_update field, I do the following:

```
$product = Product::first();
$date = $product->last_google_update;
print_r($date);
```

This outputs the following:

```
ActiveRecord\DateTime Object
(
    [model:ActiveRecord\DateTime:private] => Product Object
        (
            [errors] =>
            [attributes:ActiveRecord\Model:private] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [ext_id] => 347
                    [ext_type_id] => 1
                    [sku] => SYB-RIU-SUP
                    [url] => http://www.storeyourboard.com/sup-storage-rack.html
                    [name] => SUP Wall Storage Rack
                    [thumbnail_url] => https://cdn2.bigcommerce.com/server2100/6p8lmnk/products/347/images/2292/standup_paddle_board_rack__43491.1392317669.225.360.jpg?c=2
                    [sort_order] => 20
                    [profitability] => 40
                    [last_google_update] => ActiveRecord\DateTime Object
 *RECURSION*
                    [last_internal_update] =>
                    [discontinued] => 0
                    [stock_notes] =>
                    [deleted] => 0
                    [created_on] => ActiveRecord\DateTime Object
                        (
                            [model:ActiveRecord\DateTime:private] => Product Object
 *RECURSION*
                            [attribute_name:ActiveRecord\DateTime:private] => created_on
                            [date] => 2014-03-25 22:31:58
                            [timezone_type] => 3
                            [timezone] => UTC
                        )

                )

            [__dirty:ActiveRecord\Model:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [__readonly:ActiveRecord\Model:private] =>
            [__relationships:ActiveRecord\Model:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [__new_record:ActiveRecord\Model:private] =>
        )

    [attribute_name:ActiveRecord\DateTime:private] => last_google_update
    [date] => 2014-05-21 05:01:12
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)
```

So the get the actual date, I tried this:

```
print_r($date->date);
```

However, this gives the following error:

```
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined property: ActiveRecord\DateTime::$date</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/test.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 16</p>

</div>
```

But, if I include a call to `get_active_vars()` first, it works:

```
print_r(get_object_vars($date))
print_r($date->date);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [date] => 2014-05-21 05:01:12
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)
2014-05-21 05:01:12
```

To summarize:

1. Are the `*RECURSION*` flags expected?
2. How do I work with datetime fields and how do I access the actual dates?

Answer (score 0):

*RECURSION* is not good defenetly
I am not sure but

```
  [model:ActiveRecord\DateTime:private] => Product Object
```

somehow you have product object in a dateTime so and class trying to parse it that is why recursion.

try to see configuration of the module

Answer (score 0):

So solution is to use format function on the date object property.

```
$date->date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```